# Installation completed but not saved to hard disk

Tags: installation, usb

I am new to ubuntu and am installing ubuntu from a usb stick.I install it and it installs fully and asks me to restart computer and when i do i have to install it again as it doesnt save ubuntu in my hard disk

Answer (score 0):

Remove the installation medium(live-usb device or live-disk).After that change the boot-order to hard-disk as the first option in bios.

Answer (score 0):

Oh huh - sounds like your Ubuntu was installed ON THE USB.  Re-run the installation, and by the time you arrive the section for partitioning your disk, be sure to pick /dev/sda and that'll be your primary hard drive mount.

Answer (score 0):

After you install Ubuntu and restart your computer, make sure you remove USB stick, because your computer will boot from USB again. If you don't remove it, just shutdown your computer, remove USB stick and turn it on again